# How do I create dictionary from pandas columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I am creating dictionary by deleting rows where `checker` column is `false`

how can I create `s3_range_dict`, without deleting rows
and just checking
whether checker column is true, if it is then add that row's `url` and `name` to `dictionary`

```
df_s3_range.drop(df_s3_range[df_s3_range['checker'] == False].index, inplace=True)

s3_range_dict = pd.Series(
    df_s3_range.url.values, index=df_s3_range.name).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df_s3_range[df_s3_range['checker'] == True].set_index('name')['url'].to_dict()
```

Comment: thanks. one suggestion : it should be set_index('name')['url'].